# Перезагрузка страницы при получении данных с Express-сервера fetch-запросом

Tags: node.js, express, fetch

На странице существует форма отправки изображений,
события в которой обрабатывает скрипт **fetch_upload.js**

```js
  const form = document.getElementById('upload');
  const button = document.getElementById('img-upload');
 
  button.addEventListener('click', fetchReq, false);
 
  function fetchReq() {
    fetch('/form', {
      method: 'POST',
      data: new FormData(form)
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

```html
  <form id="upload" action="/form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="img">Загрузите фотографию</label><br>
      <input type="file" name="img" id="img">
      <button id="img-upload">Отправить</button><br>
  </form>
 
  <script src="js/fetch_upload.js"></script>
```

Запрос на стороне сервера обрабатывается вот так

```js
   app.post('/form', (req, res) => {
       new formidable.IncomingForm().parse(req)
           .on('fileBegin', (name, file) => {
               file.path = __dirname + '/public/' + file.name;
           })
           .on('file', (name, file) => {
            
           });
       res.status('200').json({
           name: "Fileл",
           description: "some text information"
       });
   });
```

В результате чего ответ сервера должен благополучно выводиться в консоль,
теоретически не заставляя страницу перезагружаться.
И в общем всё отрабатывает правильно, но затем вместо страницы
браузер отображает входящий **json**. Как сделать так, чтобы этого не происходило
и в дальнейшем данные из **json**'a поместить на эту же страницу?

Предвосхищая ответы с использованием **event**.*defaultPrevenred()*
в функции обработчика:
если поместить данный код в функцию **fetchReq** то обработка 
ответа сервера произойдет правильно, но файл на сервер **передан не будет**.
Тоже самое произойдёт если назначить тегу **button** атрибут *type="button"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось сервер всё отрабатывал правильно. 
Проблема заключалась в нескольких моментах:

1.Тег `form` необходимо использовать без специальных атрибутов,
но указать, что `button` относиться именно к этой форме

```
<form id="upload">
     <label for="img">Загрузите фотографию</label><br>
     <input type="file" name="img" id="img">
     <button form="upload" id="img-upload">Отправить</button><br>
 </form>
```

2.Слегка подправить работу с экземпляром `new FormData()`

```
document.querySelector('#img-upload')
  .addEventListener('click', upload, false);

function upload() {

  let input = document.querySelector('#img');
  let uploadData = new FormData();
  uploadData.append(input.files[0].name, input.files[0]);

  fetch('/form', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: uploadData 
  }).then(
    response => response.json()
  ).then(
    success => console.log(success)
  ).catch(
    error => console.log(error)
  );
}
```

Надеюсь этот пример кому-то поможет. Решение нашлось благодаря примеру
с этого [ресурса](https://only-to-top.ru/blog/programming/2019-09-17-otpravka-dannyh-fetch-api.html).